# How can I get the days of the month by using php?

Tags: php, date

[image]I want to display the dates of respective days in particular month. How can I do it? I only manage to input the month and show all the dates.

```html
<html>
<body>
<form method="POST">
Day (Eg: Sunday) : <input name="day" required type="text" size="30" style="height:30px;" /> <br/><br/>
Month (Eg: 7) : <input name="month" required type="text" size="30" style="height:30px;" /> <br/><br/>
<input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Log In" style="background-color: #2E9AFE; border: 1px solid #084B8A;  padding: 1px 3px; color:#fff; width:60px; height:30px;" />
</form>

<?php

 $day=$_POST['day'];
 $month=$_POST['month'];
 
    function getDates($y, $m)
 {
  return new DatePeriod(
   new DateTime("first sunday of $y-$m"),
   DateInterval::createFromDateString('next sunday'),
   new DateTime("last day of $y-$m")
  );
 }

 foreach (getDates(2015, $month) as $getDay) {
  echo $getDay->format("l, Y-m-d\n");
 }

 
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You want to display all the days of the month given ?

Comment: yes~ like i just want to display all the monday of august... do u know how to make it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to give only the month as input then iterate it with total number of days in the month

Here's the [eval](https://eval.in/399159)

```
<?php
$Days=array();
$Month = 8;
for($d=1; $d<=31; $d++)
{
    $Time=mktime(12, 0, 0, $Month, $d, '2015');          
    if (date('m', $Time)==$Month)       
        $Days[]=date('Y-m-d-D', $Time);
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($Days);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

**Note :**

1. I have given the year directly where you can give it as dynamic (User's choice).
2. The Days in the month is given directly as `31` you shall find the number of the days and give that too.

**Update :**

As the OP wants to get only the `Monday` dates.

```
<?php
$Days=array();
$Month = 12;
for($d=1; $d<=31; $d++)
{
    $Time=mktime(12, 0, 0, $Month, $d, '2014');          
    if (date('m', $Time)==$Month)       
        $Day=date('D', $Time);
        if($Day=='Mon')
        {
        $Days[]=date('Y-m-d-D', $Time);
        }
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($Days);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Here's the [updated eval](https://eval.in/399163)

Comment: but i want the date of all the monday of august.. not the total of monday in august

Comment: Yes, just a minute :)

Comment: why am I not able to change the sunday into $day like this? It pop up error                                       

"    function getDates($y, $m)
 {
  return new DatePeriod(
   new DateTime("first: .$day. "of $y-$m"),
   DateInterval::createFromDateString('next $day'),
   new DateTime("last day of $y-$m")
  );
 } "

Comment: Here's the eval. It will give you all the `Mondays` of the month https://eval.in/399163

Comment: but your coding is just an array.

Comment: @wendy Yes, you can iterate it using simple `foreach`. How you want to display those dates ?

Comment: i have edited my question by adding the photo. How can I get the output?

Comment: Here's the eval for your need https://eval.in/399181 .. If you need to display inside textbox then https://eval.in/399185

Answer (score 0):

```
 $first_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("first  Sunday of this month", strtotime('01-07-2015')));
 $last_date  = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("last  Sunday of this month", strtotime('01-07-2015')));
 $days[]       = $first_date;
while(strtotime($first_date) <= strtotime($last_date)) {

    $first_date =   date('Y-m-d', strtotime("next  Sunday ", strtotime($first_date)));
    if(strtotime($first_date) <= strtotime($last_date)) {
        $days[] = $first_date;
    }

}
  echo '<pre>';print_r($days);exit;
```